# Change Eclipse Layout Orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I want to know how to change the orientation of my `layout`. 
In `manifest` I have:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

In `layout.xml` I have

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

but when I click the "layout" `button` it still appears as a vertical `layout`.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a dropdown within the layout editor that allows you to select landscape or portrait orientation.

Comment: Well I thought this... however

I have 
Devices
(which has a custom which opesn up Device Configuration)
Config
(which is empty)
Locale
(which has ANY)

and then a theme selector

but thats it...

if i select Device and make a new one... there is a add remove thing that comes up and I can add a orientation parameter and then change it to landscape... but there is a lot of other stuff that looks like it should be messed with as well... what should i do?

Comment: Config is the one to change, it should have landscape and portrait options there.  I'm not sure why it's empty for you.

Comment: My drop downs are all empty as well.  I don't seem to be able to set anything up in them either.